# How to dim the background of a custom layout?

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom layout which extends viewgroup in order to implement a sliding menu similar to the one in this video at 1:18: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeR7McJIltk

However, what I don't know how to do is dim the background content when the menu is sliding in.

Comment: Inflate a layout on top of the view with a black or grey background and use `setAlpha(Float);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        //your views are here

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cc000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And make your `dim` `FrameLayout` visible only when menu is opened, and invisible when it closed

Comment: A small question, which one is better, in terms of performance, using any layout like `FrameLayout` you are using, or plain ol' `View`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your method i have thought of. What make me reluctant to use that method is i can't gradually dim the background that way. Once you add the framelayout on top then the background is dim to that color. Is there a way for me to dim my background graduall and the level of darkness is base on how much is the sliding menu is open??

Comment: @KevinMurvie I believe view should be faster, because `FrameLayout` is descendant of view class. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JustCurious I think there is a callback of that menu view, which will be show you progress of swipping, so you can use it and change color of `dim` layout depends on position of menu. Actually all what are you doing is outdated, and you should use [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: The effect i am trying to achieve is similar to the sliding menu dimming effect in the google drive app

Comment: @Divers Alrighty, thanks, because I've been doing `View` `match_parent` with `background:="somecolor"` for quite a while now and don't really wanna change my whole code lol

Comment: @KevinMurvie close question with marking my answer as right one then

Comment: @Divers Just a small info.. I am not the question creator lol

Comment: @KevinMurvie ahaha =) Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Give background like this.
android:background="#8000"